# Enable code folding in bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Is it possible to enable code folding in `bookdown` when using the `gitbook` output format? For example, using the `config` tag `code_folding = hide`, which is used with the `html` output format.

Comment: No, it is not supported in the gitbook output format. Sorry.