# Code folding in bookdown

Tags: javascript, html, r, code-folding, bookdown

The Code folding option in RMarkdown for html documents is awesome. That option makes the programmatic methodology transparent for those who are interested, without forcing the audience to scroll through miles of code. The tight placement of code with prose and interactive graphical output makes the whole project more accessible to a wider audience, and furthermore it reduces the need for additional documentation.

For a larger project, I'm using bookdown, and it works great. The only problem is that there is no code-folding option. 
Code folding is not currently enabled in bookdown. (see [Enable code folding in bookdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947867/enable-code-folding-in-bookdown) )

I know I don't need an option to make it happen. I just need to paste the right code in the right place or places. But what code and where?

A viable alternative would be to put the code chunk below the chunk's outputs in the page. Or, finally, to put them as an appendix. I could do that with html but not reproducible like rbookdown.

Comment: Here is my hint: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/misc/toggleR.js Use the `includes` option to include it. You have to understand JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Global Hide/Show button for the entire page

To use @Yihui's hint for a button that fold all code in the html output, you need to paste the following code in an external file (I named it `header.html` here):

Edit: I modified function `toggle_R` so that the button shows `Hide Global` or `Show Global` when clicking on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// toggle visibility of R source blocks in R Markdown output
function toggle_R() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('r');
  if (x.length == 0) return;
  function toggle_vis(o) {
    var d = o.style.display;
    o.style.display = (d == 'block' || d == '') ? 'none':'block';
  }

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var y = x[i];
    if (y.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'pre') toggle_vis(y);
  }

    var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
    if (elem.value === "Hide Global") elem.value = "Show Global";
    else elem.value = "Hide Global";
}

document.write('<input onclick="toggle_R();" type="button" value="Hide Global" id="myButton1" style="position: absolute; top: 10%; right: 2%; z-index: 200"></input>')

</script>
```

In this script, you are able to modify the position and css code associated to the button directly with the `style` options or add it in your css file. I had to set the `z-index` at a high value to be sure it appears over other divisions.
Note that this javascript code only fold R code called with `echo=TRUE`, which is attributed a `class="r"` in the html. This is defined by command `var x = document.getElementsByClassName('r');`

Then, you call this file in the YAML header of your rmarkdown script, as in the example below:

````
---
title: "Toggle R code"
author: "StatnMap"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
  bookdown::gitbook:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
---

Stackoverflow question
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360998/code-folding-in-bookdown>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

## New Edit: Local Hide/show button for each chunk

I finally found the solution !
While looking at the code folding behavior for normal html output (no bookdown), I was able to add it to bookdown. The main javascript function needs to find `.sourceCode` class divisions to work with bookdown. However, this also requires complementary javascript functions of [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/), but not all. This works with `gitbook` and `html_document2`.
Here are the steps:

1. Create a `js` folder in the same directory than your Rmd file
2. Download javascript functions `transition.js` and `collapse.js` here for instance: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v3.3.7/js and store them in your `js` folder
3. Create a new file in the `js` folder called `codefolding.js` with the following code. This is the same as for rmarkdown code_folding option but with `pre.sourceCode` added to find R code chunks:

`codefolding.js` code:

```
window.initializeCodeFolding = function(show) {

  // handlers for show-all and hide all
  $("#rmd-show-all-code").click(function() {
    $('div.r-code-collapse').each(function() {
      $(this).collapse('show');
    });
  });
  $("#rmd-hide-all-code").click(function() {
    $('div.r-code-collapse').each(function() {
      $(this).collapse('hide');
    });
  });

  // index for unique code element ids
  var currentIndex = 1;

  // select all R code blocks
  var rCodeBlocks = $('pre.sourceCode, pre.r, pre.python, pre.bash, pre.sql, pre.cpp, pre.stan');
  rCodeBlocks.each(function() {

    // create a collapsable div to wrap the code in
    var div = $('<div class="collapse r-code-collapse"></div>');
    if (show)
      div.addClass('in');
    var id = 'rcode-643E0F36' + currentIndex++;
    div.attr('id', id);
    $(this).before(div);
    $(this).detach().appendTo(div);

    // add a show code button right above
    var showCodeText = $('<span>' + (show ? 'Hide' : 'Code') + '</span>');
    var showCodeButton = $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs code-folding-btn pull-right"></button>');
    showCodeButton.append(showCodeText);
    showCodeButton
        .attr('data-toggle', 'collapse')
        .attr('data-target', '#' + id)
        .attr('aria-expanded', show)
        .attr('aria-controls', id);

    var buttonRow = $('<div class="row"></div>');
    var buttonCol = $('<div class="col-md-12"></div>');

    buttonCol.append(showCodeButton);
    buttonRow.append(buttonCol);

    div.before(buttonRow);

    // update state of button on show/hide
    div.on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
      showCodeText.text('Code');
    });
    div.on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
      showCodeText.text('Hide');
    });
  });

}
```

4. In the following rmarkdown script, all three functions are read and included as is in the header, so that the `js` folder in not useful for the final document itself. When reading the js functions, I also added the option to `show` code blocks by default, but you can choose to hide them with `hide`.

rmarkdown code:

````
---
title: "Toggle R code"
author: "StatnMap"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
  bookdown::gitbook:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
---

Stackoverflow question
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360998/code-folding-in-bookdown>


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# Add a common class name for every chunks
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = TRUE)
```
```{r htmlTemp3, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
codejs <- readr::read_lines("js/codefolding.js")
collapsejs <- readr::read_lines("js/collapse.js")
transitionjs <- readr::read_lines("js/transition.js")

htmlhead <- 
  paste('
<script>',
paste(transitionjs, collapse = "\n"),
'</script>
<script>',
paste(collapsejs, collapse = "\n"),
'</script>
<script>',
paste(codejs, collapse = "\n"),
'</script>
<style type="text/css">
.code-folding-btn { margin-bottom: 4px; }
.row { display: flex; }
.collapse { display: none; }
.in { display:block }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.initializeCodeFolding("show" === "show");
});
</script>
', sep = "\n")

readr::write_lines(htmlhead, path = "header.html")
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

```{r plot}
plot(cars)
```
````

This script shows the buttons in the Rstudio browser but does not work well. However, this is ok with firefox.
You'll see that there is a little `css` in this code, but of course you can modify the position and color and whatever you want on these buttons with some more css.

### Edit: Combine Global and local buttons

**Edit 2017-11-13: Global code-folding button well integrated with individual bloc buttons.** Function `toggle_R` is finally not necessary, but you need to get function `dropdown.js` in bootstrap.

Global button is called directly in the code chunk when calling `js` files:

````
```{r htmlTemp3, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
codejs <- readr::read_lines("/mnt/Data/autoentrepreneur/js/codefolding.js")
collapsejs <- readr::read_lines("/mnt/Data/autoentrepreneur/js/collapse.js")
transitionjs <- readr::read_lines("/mnt/Data/autoentrepreneur/js/transition.js")
dropdownjs <- readr::read_lines("/mnt/Data/autoentrepreneur/js/dropdown.js")

htmlhead <- c(
  paste('
<script>',
paste(transitionjs, collapse = "\n"),
'</script>
<script>',
paste(collapsejs, collapse = "\n"),
'</script>
<script>',
paste(codejs, collapse = "\n"),
'</script>
<script>',
paste(dropdownjs, collapse = "\n"),
'</script>
<style type="text/css">
.code-folding-btn { margin-bottom: 4px; }
.row { display: flex; }
.collapse { display: none; }
.in { display:block }
.pull-right > .dropdown-menu {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
.open > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.initializeCodeFolding("show" === "show");
});
</script>
', sep = "\n"),
  paste0('
<script>
document.write(\'<div class="btn-group pull-right" style="position: absolute; top: 20%; right: 2%; z-index: 200"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" data-_extension-text-contrast=""><span>Code</span> <span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 50px;"><li><a id="rmd-show-all-code" href="#">Show All Code</a></li><li><a id="rmd-hide-all-code" href="#">Hide All Code</a></li></ul></div>\')
</script>
')
)

readr::write_lines(htmlhead, path = "/mnt/Data/autoentrepreneur/header.html")
```
````

The new global button shows a dropdown menu to choose between "show all code" or "hide all code". Using `window.initializeCodeFolding("show" === "show")` all codes are shown by default, whereas using `window.initializeCodeFolding("show" === "hide")`, all codes are hidden by default.

Comment: Thanks! This adds a button on each page, how would I add a button for each chunk, like in rmarkdown?

Comment: Sorry, I am currently trying to use this answer but without success for the moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944197/add-a-css-class-to-single-code-chunks-in-rmarkdown. This may be combined with this one for including css class in the chunks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944197/add-a-css-class-to-single-code-chunks-in-rmarkdown. If I succeed, I will update my answer.

Comment: I added the script in the current "not working" stage, maybe somebody can help see what is the problem.

Comment: Ok, now I found the solution to show/hide each chunk of code. You can then use your own css to show nice buttons.

Comment: I've tried the show/hide for each chunk of code solution, but it seems to create a new button every time there is a blank line within a code chunk. Also, when I click to hide it, the chunk (or portion of chunk) is reduced to a single line with a vertical scroll bar, not hidden.

Comment: The vertical scroll bar was because the div was not really hidden but just reduced to 0. I modified the css  for `.collapse` and `.in` for that. However, I do not see problems with blank lines. I tried with `gitbook` and `html_document2`. What do you mean ?

Comment: Thanks @yihui for the bonus. To celebrate that, I updated the code for the same global button as in classical `rmarkdown` html. Much nicer. I also implemented it with `blogdown` on my website...

Comment: Is there a way to modify the javascript for the Global option to initially have all the code folded (i.e. not showing)?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can use `window.initializeCodeFolding("show" === "hide")`. Also I recommend reading the complete blog post about it : 
https://statnmap.com/2017-11-13-enable-code-folding-in-bookdown-and-blogdown/

Comment: Hi @SébastienRochette, I've been trying to get the hide-all button to stay fixed next to the `h1` title (so when I scroll it does stay in one place like when using `html_document`). I've tried playing with the CSS of the button itself but it always moves with the scroll. Then I tried to add it manually after the `window.initializeCodeFolding` is run, putting it into a string `var str = <div class="btn-group...` and adding it like this: `$( '[class^="section level1"]' ).prepend( str );` but the button loses all extra CSS+functionality I have put before! Do you maybe know any quick fix?

Comment: `position: fixed` with `top: some_value` and `right: some_value` for class `code-folding-btn` should be enough in css

Comment: for bs4_book I had to remove the general - multi - buttons. Hope someone comes with a solution for that.

Comment: Anyone got this to work in a bs4_book? It just reopens the code chunks when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 5):

I made the `R` package `rtemps` which includes a ready-to-use bookdown template **with code-folding buttons** among others (largely based on Sébastien Rochette's answer/post). Check it [here](https://github.com/bblodfon/rtemps)!

Comment: This was really great, thanks. I love way that the code panels open and close smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a filter for pandoc that:

- wraps all code blocks in HTML5 `<details>` tags
- adds a local button to fold/unfold code
- button text toggles between "Show code" and "Hide code" (feel free to customize) via `onclick` javascript event

Filter can be found [here](https://github.com/sergiocorreia/panflute-filters/blob/master/filters/collapse_code.py). Needs [python](https://www.python.org/) distribution with [panflute](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/) installed to run.

Add to bookdown via `pandoc_args: ["-F", "path/to/collapse_code.py"]`