# Work-around for code folding in Hugo blogdown websites

Tags: javascript, r, hugo, blogdown

In Rmarkdown documents there is a [code folding option](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#code_folding)--`code_folding: hide`. This option is not available for Hugo websites generated with the `blogdown` package ([see this recently opened feature request](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/214)). Has anyone come up with a work-around for this? Even some JavaScript and HTML code that can be added on a post-by-post basis?

As an example, blogdown generates a default Hugo site with the Hugo-lithium theme when you run the following command in an new directory:

```
blogdown::new_site().
```

One of the posts generated for this default is below. I'd be interested in adding code folding to this example, that is, a hide/show button that the webpage above each R code block.

---

````
title: "Hello R Markdown"
author: "Frida Gomam"
date: 2015-07-23T21:13:14-05:00
categories: ["R"]
tags: ["R Markdown", "plot", "regression"]
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(collapse = TRUE)
```

# R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
fit <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
fit
```

# Including Plots

You can also embed plots. See Figure \@ref(fig:pie) for example:

```{r pie, fig.cap='A fancy pie chart.', tidy=FALSE}
par(mar = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  pie(
    c(280, 60, 20),
    c('Sky', 'Sunny side of pyramid', 'Shady side of pyramid'),
    col = c('#0292D8', '#F7EA39', '#C4B632'),
    init.angle = -50, border = NA
 )
````

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/q/45360998/559676 may be helpful (you have to have some basic knowledge of JS).

Comment: Thanks Yihui! I know enough to follow examples so I'll give it a try.