# Global code folding in bookdown with default set to "hide global"

Tags: javascript, default, bookdown, folding

The very first answer of [this wonderful post shows a straight forward javascript that will to insert a toggle to hide all code in a bookdown doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45360998/code-folding-in-bookdown).

Although I have tried many different variations and tried to understand this post discussing  [options to set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function), I cannot seem to figure out how to set the default of the resulting bookdown doc in the first referenced post to hide all code as a default and have the toggle show the reader the code when they want to see it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to understand anything about default parameters since no function is called with arguments in that script. All you need is to append a line `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', toggle_R);` in the bottom of the script which will hide everything once the elements have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer above [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi).  Nice one! I will add the entire script modified as per the section. It of course is saved as the `header.htm` file pointed to in the `index.Rmd` yaml as described by another leader named [Sébastien Rochette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7405597/s%C3%A9bastien-rochette) in his post linked in the question.

It seems that the toggle switch needed to be named as universal (i.e `Show/Hide Code`) since the state of each "chapter" of the bookdown doc did not always jive with what the toggle button was displaying when it was hit when reviewing other "chapters"...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// toggle visibility of R source blocks in R Markdown output
function toggle_R() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('r');
  if (x.length == 0) return;
  function toggle_vis(o) {
    var d = o.style.display;
    o.style.display = (d == 'block' || d == '') ? 'none':'block';
  }

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var y = x[i];
    if (y.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'pre') toggle_vis(y);
  }

    var elem = document.getElementById("myButton1");
    if (elem.value === "Show/Hide Code") elem.value = "Show/Hide Code";
    else elem.value = "Show/Hide Code";
}

document.write('<input onclick="toggle_R();" type="button" value="Show/Hide Code" id="myButton1" style="position: absolute; top: 10%; right: 2%; z-index: 200"></input>')

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', toggle_R);

</script>
```