# How to enable code folding for bookdown::bs4_book

Tags: javascript, html, r, bookdown, code-folding

I would like to use code folding in bookdown::bs4_book.

I have tried [Sébastien Rochette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45501553/22025586) solution and using the hide_code.html from the [rtemps](https://github.com/bblodfon/rtemps)  package which both produce similar results.

The code folding buttons show up and work to expand the code chunk but only for a second, then it collapses and disappears again.

I think the issue is that both of these option are written for bootstraps 3 and are not compatible with bs4_book? But I don't know javascript so I don't know how to fix it to get it to work.

Comment: Have the same exact issue, mine also unfold as soon as I click on them.